# Azure cosmos DB correlated subquery not working as expected

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

The below query is not working in Azure Cosmos DB. It is not fetching any result. Can anyone tell me where and what That I am missing. Trying to get recent item based on timestamp from multiple same sessionId entries.

```
SELECT c.payload, c.domainname
FROM c JOIN t IN c.domainname
WHERE c.payload.sessionTimestamp = 
(SELECT VALUE MAX(t.payload.sessionTimestamp) FROM t 
WHERE c.payload.sessionId = t.payload.sessionId)
```

sample JSON structure is as below.

```
[{
        "domainname": "cardiology",
        "payload": {
            "sessionId": "ABC1234",
            "sessionTimestamp": "2020-02-04T10:14:43.507Z",
            "values": [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
        }
    },
    {
        "domainname": "cardiology",
        "payload": {
            "sessionId": "ABC1234",
            "sessionTimestamp": "2020-02-05T10:10:43.507Z",
            "values": [60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: It would really help if you edited your question to show an example document, especially one where you feel your query would've worked. Without any sample data, I don't think this is answerable.

Comment: @DavidMakogon, I have edited the question with sample data structure.

Comment: what is t here, another table ?

Comment: @biswpo , 't' is same 'c' . I used self join in the above query based on 'domainname' field. Above query is executing but not fetching any records.

Comment: @Balaji211 You must make the subquery work separately. You can not use `t` in your sebquery.

Comment: @Balaji211 What is the complete structure of your json document? What you provided is an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly,your query sql doesn't match your sample data.I suppose that your documents in db as below:

```
{
        "domainname": "cardiology",
        "payload": {
            "sessionId": "ABC1234",
            "sessionTimestamp": "2020-02-04T10:14:43.507Z",
            "values": [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
        }
    },
    {
        "domainname": "cardiology",
        "payload": {
            "sessionId": "ABC1234",
            "sessionTimestamp": "2020-02-05T10:10:43.507Z",
            "values": [60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
        }
    }
```

It seems that you want to implement `self-join` with cosmos db which is not supported actually.So,i don't think `JOIN` should be used here.

> Trying to get recent item based on timestamp from multiple same
>   sessionId entries.

You need GROUP BY here probably.

sql:

```
SELECT max(c.payload.sessionTimestamp),c.payload.sessionId from c
group by c.payload.sessionId
```

result:

[image]

Then you would get `sessionId` array which could be used in next sql. Such as `... where c.sessionId in [sessionId array]`

Comment: seems like, it is not possible to get my requirement in a single sql query.....

Comment: @Balaji211 yeah,not support in a single query.